# How to pause a Windows console program being debugged

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, debugging, console

When a C# or VB.Net **console** program is **debugged** the console **closes** as soon as the program **ends** and there is no opportunity to see the output. How do I keep it open?

Comment: Note that this is a question that I provided an answer to. The answer does not exist previously. If I had posted my answer in the other question then I would not have gotten recognition.

Answer (score 2):

I often see questions like this. Often the suggestion is to use Console.ReadKey() or something like that but that is inappropriate for production use. My preference is to simply put a breakpoint on the last line of Main, or somewhere like that.

I think however that a good alternative is to use Debugger.IsAttached to determine if the console program is being debugged. The following is a simple sample of how it can be used. This is C# code but I hope it is easy to convert to VB .Net.

```
using System;
namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing");
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Debugging; press a key to continue...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Checking for a debugger is not enough, this will also fail if the user creates a shortcut to the program on his desktop.

Comment: For a shortcut to the program on the desktop, I do not consider it a failure since it is normal behavior for console programs. The user expects to need to do something for console programs, we do not need to put something special in our code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define DEBUG
// ...
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif
```

Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

Comment: Will that eliminate the relevant code from being executed for a debug build being executed outside the debugger? Outside the debugger, we automatically get the "Press any key to continue".

Comment: @user34660 no, you need specify the build for debug/release mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to debug just Press (Ctrl+F5). Otherwise if you want to debug just put break point at last line of your code

You can use `Console.ReadKey();` at the end of you program.

`Console.ReadKey();` blocks the current thread until a character or function key is pressed.

Comment: Yes, I said a breakpoint is what I use. Note that my answer does use Console.ReadKey() except with a twist.