# C# in visual studio won't work

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I just bought my first Windows today (I have always used mac), but C# in my visual studio will not work. Running this:

```
using System;

public class Class1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

just gives me this error and does not print anything out:

```
CopyWin32Resources failed with exit App3 code 500
```

I'm getting very frustrated can someone tell me how to get passes this?

Comment: `CopyWin32Resources` is invoked if you're building a UWP application, not a Console application, and the `Console` class is unavailable in UWP contexts. What happens if you create a Console project?

Comment: Also see [How to pause a Windows console program being debugged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653344/how-to-pause-a-windows-console-program-being-debugged).

Answer (score 0):

Please choose the `Console Application` template in the New Project Dialog in the category `Templates \ Visual C# \ Windows` and copy your source code into the main method.

Then your program should start and shows a console with "Hello world". 
If you add the line `Console.ReadKey();` then the console window will remain open until you press a key.

With a Windows Console Application you can see output to the Console.